# Count number of lines of .gz files recursively on directory?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have hundreds of directories and each directory contains `.gz` file and I want to count lines of that `.gz` file.

I tried the following one liner to achieve this but it does not work says gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file

```
find . type -f -name '*.data.gz' | gunzip -c  | wc -l
```

for e.g. if there are two directories with one .gz file each, and suppose each has 100 lines, then I want 200 total lines a output.

Comment: Add an "xargs" before the "gunzip"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You were quite there...:

```
find . -type f -name '*.gz' | xargs zcat | wc -l
```

Comment: Or, just `zcat *.gz | wc -l`

Comment: Actually, OP explicitly asks for a recursive solution, so mine won't do. `zcat **/*.gz | wc -l` would be fine in `zsh` or in `bash` with `shopt -s globstar` enabled in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: @arekolek dees command accounts subfolder's .gz files, or just current directory?

Comment: @Memin `*.gz` is current directory only, `**/*.gz` is current directory and subfolders

Answer (score 4):

```
gzip -dc *.gz | wc -l
```

-d decompress
-c to STDOUT (not to disk)

or

```
gzip -dcr * | wc -l
```

-d decompress

-c to STDOUT (not to disk)

-r recursive (look in directorties)

Comment: `zcat` (`gzcat` on some systems) is equivalent to `gzip -dc` and `gunzip -c`

Comment: Also, the second option will (try to) output all files, instead of just with `.gz` extension, possibly printing messages about files `not in gzip format`.

Answer (score 3):

my directory:

```
.
├── a.gz
├── b.gz
└── t
    └── f.gz
```

command to echo and count lines of every gz file found:

```
find . -type f -name '*.gz' -exec bash -c 'echo $1;gunzip -c $1 | wc -l' dummy {} \;
```

output:

```
./a.gz
5
./b.gz
6
./t/f.gz
3
```

then, in order to obtain a grand total:

```
echo $((`find . -type f -name '*.gz' -exec bash -c 'gunzip -c $1 | wc -l' dummy {} \;  | paste -sd+`))
```

output:

```
14
```

Comment: why do we need a dummy here? I tried without dummy and it doesn't work. But I don't know why a dummy is needed.

Comment: This was helpful for getting the individual counts. The command can be improved with a double quote around `$1` -- for cases where the file name has spaces in it.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this code snippet.

```
#!/bin/bash

gzfiles=`find . -name '*.data.gz'`

total_line_count=0
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Found at:"
        for file in $gzfiles
                do
                        echo " - $file"
                        fl_line_count=`gunzip $file -c | wc -l`
                        total_line_count=`expr $total_line_count + $fl_line_count`
                done
        else
                echo "No GZIP file found :("
fi

echo "Line count: $total_line_count"
```